# Get the Key values from JSON dictionary

Tags: javascript, json, dictionary

I'm trying to get the keys from a dictionary, using javascript.

I'm getting the .json file with the dictionary uploaded by the user, and then I'd like to show to the user the keys from the dictionary they uploaded. For this, assume you can only upload a .json dictionary, and that that dictionary is being parsed to a variable that holds the dictionary.

For example, let's say I have the following dictionary

```
var dict = [
  {key1: "hello", key2: "world"},
  {key1: "test", key2: "testy test"}
]
```

and I would like to have the key1 and key2 values, for example in an string array, like:

```
var keys = ["key1", "key2"]
```

.

Is this possible? And, if so, how would I go about it?

Comment: You need to specify which language do you use and what you already have.

Comment: my apologies, I've edited the question to better explain my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you meant is

```
let dict = {key1: "hello", key2: "world"};
```

you can get keys using

```
Object.keys(dict); // ["key1", "key2"]
```

Comment: That did the trick! I was not aware of the Object.keys() function. Thank you very much